# Python Lock internal implementation

Tags: python, synchronization, locking, spinlock

Python lock seems to be the most primitive synchronization mechanism used by other synchronization variables.

I wanted to know how a python lock works? Where can I check the source code and implementation of the lock? Also, if multiple threads are waiting on the lock, which thread is woken up during a release?

Answer (score 3):

## How a python lock works?

It is NOT a simple question because of the existence of [GIL](https://realpython.com/python-gil/), have a look at this [blog](https://opensource.com/article/17/4/grok-gil).

## Source code

Usually, people use [CPython](https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/8905fcc85a6fc3ac394bc89b0bbf40897e9497a6) implement. The source code of thread module is [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/8905fcc85a6fc3ac394bc89b0bbf40897e9497a6/Modules/_threadmodule.c).

## How to pickup a thread

Any thread in waiting state has the possibility to be woken up. So you might treat it as a random pickup.